# Swift - UIImageViews arranged in UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, swift, uiimageview

Hi I have an array with URLS. How to display all images in UIScrollView like this: [image: Link]

I want to fill all space in UIScrollView with these 100 images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I don't know how to use UICollectionView and there aren't good tutorials which explain usage of UICollectionView...

Comment: It's just like a `UITableView`, but you dequeue views instead of cells. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12). [Here's another one](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/).

Comment: yes, but is full with bugs loads me only 7 of images and the function .reloadData() is work very slowly...

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to tell you, I haven't had problems with `UICollectionView` or noticed it being buggy. Setup is very similar to a table view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771795/swift-uicollectionview-repeats-duplicate-cells this is the problem

Comment: Yes I already know about UICollectionView thanks for the answer :)